# Where can I find past Titled Tuesday data

Tags: history, tournament, online-chess, database, chess.com

I'm hoping to create a dataset with Chess.com Titled Tuesday results.
I have found this link which has the tournaments https://www.chess.com/tournament/live/titled-tuesdays?&page=7  but for some reason, the list won't show anything past Page 7.
I was wondering if there is already a dataset like this. Or even getting access to the tournaments should be fine. I tried with Wayback Machine as well but no luck. I'm hoping to collect data starting from the first Titled Tuesday ( started 2014 I believe)

Comment: Have you attempted to put your problem to chess.com ? Which should be the logical starting point for your enquiries .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have started on the dataset
https://github.com/cmgchess/Titled-Tuesday-Data

With the help of Wayback Machine, I managed to access the tournaments up until March 1, 2016. Beyond that, I have no clue how to find.

Would appreciate if someone can help with the older events as well.

**UPDATE**
I completed the dataset starting from the first TT in 2014 upto now, and it gets updated every Wednesday
https://github.com/cmgchess/Titled-Tuesday-Data

Apart from that there is a pgn compilation as well contributed by [rastallian](https://github.com/rastallian)
https://github.com/rastallian/chesscom-pgn-archive
and
https://chessnerd.net/chesscom-titled-tuesday-compilation/